# Swing JPanel.add does not add the component to the panel

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java Swing. So I've faced the problem with adding components to the main window.

Here is my code.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame(){
        setTitle("Tetris");
        JComponent gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        add(gamePanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    public GamePanel(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.white);
        add(new Ball(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new StartButton(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}

public class Ball extends JComponent {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        graphics2D.setColor(Color.RED);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics2D.fillOval(40,40,10,10);
    }
}
```

When I call in the main method new MainFrame() I've got the window with Button only. There's no Ball. Could you help me please?

Comment: Where is the Ball's constructor? You have only called some super method, not the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your ball at `BorderLayout.CENTER` instead of `BorderLayout.North`

Answer (score 1):

@Marc_Alx If you place the ball in `BorderLayout.North` then it uses its default size, which is zero. Placing it in `BorderLayout.CENTER` causes it to expand to fill the panel.

If you really want it in `BorderLayout.North` then you should create a constructor for Ball that sets its preferered size.

Note also that the first line in Ball's `paintComponent()` method should be

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

to ensure the proper background color is rendered and the old ball image gets erased if you move the ball somewhere else.